# onRun of android-priority-jobqueue not called

Tags: android, android-priority-jobqueue

I am trying to integrate [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) in android but onRun is not called i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Here is my Job class

```
public class UpdateAttachmentJob extends Job {

    long id;
    String token;
    private static final String GROUP = "attachment";
    public static final int PRIORITY = 1;

    public UpdateAttachmentJob(long id,String token) {
        super(new Params(PRIORITY).requireNetwork().persist());
    this.id=id;
    this.token=token;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {

        AttachmentTable tableItem = QueryClass.getData(id);

        new UpdateAttachmentsService().updateAttachment(id, tableItem.Name, tableItem.Description, tableItem.filePath,token ,new ApiCallBack() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object object) {

                BaseClass baseClass = (BaseClass) object;
                if (baseClass.getStatus() == Constants.status) {
                    QueryClass.deleteSyncTask(id);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Object object, String message) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel() {

    }
}
```

Here is how i call the job

```
if (mjobManager==null)
            mjobManager=new JobManager(context);

        mjobManager.addJobInBackground(new UpdateAttachmentJob(id,token));
```

What am i doing wrong, how to make it work

Comment: your job requires network, do you have `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission?

Comment: @yigit   Yes i have ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Comment: is  mjobManager.start();this mandatory to start

Comment: i have tried configuring job manager before each call, still it doesnot work

Comment: no it is not mandatory. And NO you should not create a new job manager for each job (or whatever you meant by configuring in each run). Can you attach an app to the issue on github so I can try to reproduce it?

Comment: oh before that, can you create the job manager with logging enabled (see github WIKI) The logs may tell you what is wrong.

Comment: `onRun` is never called for me as well. I have `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in my manifest, and I've created my `JobManager` as a Singleton so there will only be one instance.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas, it ended up being a `Serialization` error. Make sure the class that you're trying to persist is Serializable.